# Google maps are not displayed on device with using jquerymobile

Tags: android, google-maps, cordova, jquery-mobile, store

Hello i have got a problem,
if I try to display maps with using jquerymobile on desktop browser is everything O.K.
But if I try launch on device maps are not displayed.

I using map key with key form example site where I found this solution, because app is stored in mobile cannot use Google maps API key, because is for websites only.

I found also that must create a new keystore, but i dont know where i should put this key?
Into?

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=ABQIAAAAahcO7noe62FuOIQacCQQ7RTHkUDJMJAZieEeKAqNDtpKxMhoFxQsdtJdv3FJ1dT3WugUNJb7xD-jsQ" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Or elsewhere?

I create app using phonegap, jquerymobile.

Thanks very much for any advice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you using JS API V3? From Google Maps Docs:
"Note: This version of the Google Maps JavaScript API no longer needs API keys!"

I am using jQuery Mobile and Google Maps, ran into problems regarding
map_canvas div height and related settings. What exact problem are you
seeing, no map or map in wrong place? Does firebug show anything amiss?

I've had great success with mobile examples [here](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/) . I don't use a key even though some of these examples do.

Answer (score 3):

That key (which is for the Google loader) is used in the [jquery-ui-map](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/) plugin examples. As Libby said Google Maps v3 doesn't require any API keys. 
Maybe you should start accepting some answers....